# How to configure the behavior of SendToOfficialFile.aspx

Tags: 2007, records-management

I am currently troubleshooting an issue with missing content type metadata after using `Send To` to publish document stored in secure subsite to top site document library.

The source document library isn't configured with custom "send to" target location, rather it has option under "Other Location" that sends the doument to official records

```
+------------+
|            | 
| Send To >  +------------------+
|            | Other Location   |
+------------+ Official Records | 
             |                  |
             +------------------+
```

The url associated with "Official Records" is /_layouts/sendtoofficialfile.aspx. I've opened the aspx file and it appears to be part of the SharePoint package, and not some custom code.

I need to know how it's configured. Knowing so will help me resolve the issue

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking on msdn the flow is as follows:

> **Sends the file to a records repository.**
>
> This method submits a file for archiving in a Records Center.
>
> If a Records Center Web service is configured for the current Web
>   application, users can right-click a document in a library and choose
>   Send to Records center from the edit control block menu. You can use
>   the SendToOfficialFile method to automate the same operation, perhaps
>   in an event handler or as part of a workflow.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms440019.aspx

following the above to where its stored you can now go here:

> The Records Center is intended to serve as a central repository in
>   which an organization can store and manage all of its records. The
>   Records Center supports the entire records management process, from
>   records collection through records management to records disposition.
>   Typically, a Records Center site is designed and configured by an
>   organization's records management professionals and information
>   technology (IT) staff to support an organization's file plan.
>
> The Records Center site template combines some standard features
>   available in Office SharePoint Server 2007 with some additional
>   specialized records management features to provide the following
>   capabilities:
>
> Vault abilities
>
> The Records Center has several features that help ensure the integrity
>   of the records stored within it:
>
> Records are never automatically modified by the system. This ensures
>   that records that are uploaded to a Records Center site and then
>   downloaded again later are always identical.
>
> Site administrators can easily configure the Records Center with
>   settings that prevent the direct tampering with records by versioning
>   any changes that are made to document contents and by auditing
>   specific types of changes.
>
> The Records Center allows records managers to add and maintain
>   metadata on items separately from a record's metadata, so that the
>   information that is pertinent to records management tasks can be
>   updated without modifying the underlying record.
>
> Changes to metadata are also versioned.

also this is where the info will be stored:

> Record routing     The Records Center includes a Record Routing list
>   that automatically routes incoming records (whether submitted
>   automatically or manually) to their proper location, based on their
>   record type. When a record is submitted to the Records Center, it is
>   often accompanied by additional related information, such as audit
>   history and metadata. A record's audit history is stored in the
>   Records Center as an XML file, and a record's metadata is stored both
>   in an XML file and in metadata columns on the Records Center site.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-the-records-center-site-HA010173596.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the hint on "Record Center", I found the site: `<central administration url>/_admin/OfficialFileAdmin.aspx`